# Enabling pretty permalinks with Docker, Multisite Wordpress and Caddy

Tags: php, multisite, wp-config, server

My task is to migrate several existing blogs, which where hosted on individual instances, to a multisite instance.

The entire multisite instance is dockerized due to company policy and using "Caddy" rather than ISS or Apache. The server is - among other - running the following containers:

- WordPress (`wordpress:6.2.0-php8.0-fpm-alpine`)
- MariaDB (`mariadb:10.11.3-jammy`)
- Caddy (`caddy:2.6.4-alpine`)

The blogs seem to work as required except for pretty permalinks.

When trying to change the permalink structure, I can either go for "ugly links"; i.e. `url.com/?p=123` or semi-pretty links `url.com/index.php/%postname%` (all other options also include `index.php`).

However, the previous instances where configured to use the pretty link schema: `url.com/%postname%`.

---

**TL;DR:**

- How can I enable pretty links (without `/index.php/`) when using Postname as permalink structure?
- The server is **NOT** using Apache nor ISS. Instead it's using Caddy.

*Additional context:*

- The blogs are setup using subdirectories.

---

Caddyfile:

```
www.url.com {
    root * /var/www/html
    php_fastcgi wordpress:9000
    file_server
    encode gzip
    uri path_regexp ^/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/wp- /wp-
    log
}
```

(Relevant Parts of) docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb:10.11.3-jammy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ENV_MARIA_DB_ROOT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${ENV_MARIA_DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    image: wordpress:6.2.0-php8.0-fpm-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - database:database
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${ENV_MARIA_DB_ROOT}
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
        define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'url.com');
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "465:465"
    volumes:
      - wordpress-data:/var/www/html
  caddy:
    container_name: caddy
    image: caddy:2.6.4-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "443:443/udp"
      - "2019:2019"
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - wordpress-data:/var/www/html
    links:
      - wordpress

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
  wordpress-data:
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I encountered a bug or my configuration is faulty.

I cannot change the permalinks structure in the default `Settings > Permalinks` views without introducing the `/index.php/`-part. This behavior does not change, whether the user is a Super-Admin or a regular Site-Admin.

However, as a Super-Admin, you can overwrite the permalink structure in the network management view

`Your websites > Websites > All websites > (YourSite.com submenu) Edit > Settings > permalink_structure`.

Using this, I was able to get rid of the pesky `/index.php/` part.